# how do i do an alert response from a servlet?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I would like to do an alert confirmation when user submits a form, how do I do that?

I've used:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
response.setContentType("text/html");  
out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");  
out.println("alert('form submitted!');");  
out.println("</script>");
```

but it leaves the page blank.

how do I do the alert without refreshing the background page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use AJAX. All normal requests result in a new page being served.

btw: alert() is a bit of a blunt tool and is not considered be part of a "good user experience". You may want to have a modal dialog instead.

Comment: modal dialog for a form submission? do you by chance have a short sample?

Comment: See: http://www.designlabelblog.com/2009/03/20-ways-to-create-javascript-modal.html